# kmeans bug when specifying starting cluster centers in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to run kmeans step by step in R. When I set iter.max = 1 and specify the starting cluster centers in place of k, the algorithm seems to be running until  it converges instead of the specified 1 iteration.

Could anyone confirm this is a known bug? If not, anything I am missing?

Here is my code for reference:

```
# Set up data
data <- data.frame(names = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3", "C1", "C2"), 
                   x = c(2, 2, 8, 5, 7, 6, 1, 4),
                   y = c(10, 5, 4, 8, 5, 4, 2, 9))

initial_centers <- matrix(c(2, 5, 1, 10, 8, 2), ncol=2)

# Run k means for 1 iteration
model <- kmeans(data[,-1], initial_centers, iter.max=1)
model$centers

# Actual Output:
#          x        y
# 1 3.666667 9.000000
# 2 7.000000 4.333333
# 3 1.500000 3.500000

# Expected Output:
#          x        y
# 1 2.000000 10.00000
# 2 6.000000 6.000000
# 3 1.500000 3.500000
```

Comment: Why do you think this is a bug rather than convergence in 1 iteration? If you set `iter.max` to 10 and then look at `summary(model)`, it still only runs for 1 iteration before it converges.

Comment: I see it now. Thanks! 
My understanding was the algorithm works by assigning each point to the nearest cluster and iterates. If that was the case, it would have converged in the 4th iteration. But, seems like it is cleverer than that as Anony-Mousse clarifies in the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default k-means algorithm in R is more clever than what you learned in class. It's Hartigan and Wong's algorithm.

If you want to assign each point to the nearest predefined center, don't abuse kmeans for this. Instead, just computer the distances and use `argmin`.